# Gridview, Listview, Repeater - Which Control is good?

Tags: vb.net

Using vb.net 2008

I want to display a table in the form, so i want to use the controls like grid view, datalist view, list view, repeater. From the above four control which is more flexible.

Before I used list view in vb6. But in vb.net 2008, i don't no which control i have to select.

I tried a same list view in vb.net, But i don't how to display as a table view.

Can any one help to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView does what you want, real easy to set up to your needs.

Comment: He's listing ASP.NET controls, and DataGridView is a WinForms control, no?